# Updating a partitioned table with aligned index locks all partitions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-partitioning

**part function and schema:**

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION SegmentPartitioningFunction (smallint)
    AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) ;
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME SegmentPartitioningSchema
    AS PARTITION SegmentPartitioningFunction ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
GO
```

**I have a table (Note the table is M:N) :**

```
  PartTable 
  (
   prd_id int, 
   cat_id smallint, 
   datacolumn smallint,
   primary key (prd_id, cat_id) on SegmentPartitioningSchema(cat_id)
  ) on SegmentPartitioningSchema(cat_id)
```

**NOTE:** I tried all 3 combinations (`part. table`, `part. index`, `part table and index`)

In addition I have an index on `PRD_ID` and `CAT_ID` by them selves as they are Foreing keys.

I set `LOCK_ESCALATION` to `AUTO` as confirmed using this select:

```
SELECT lock_escalation_desc FROM sys.tables
```

Now, what I am trying to do is and by my understending should work:

```
begin tran
update PartTable set DataColumn = DataColumn where cat_id = 1
-- commit tran -- this doesnt happen yet
```

and at the same time in different connection

```
begin tran
update PartTable set DataColumn = DataColumn where cat_id = 2
-- commit tran -- this doesnt happen yet
```

**The execution plan**

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/MgK6whYG

Bonus Q: Why is the TOP operator used?

By my understanding, I should get `IX` locks on the partition and only one one partition at the same time, which means both transactions can complete at the same time and the second one where `cat_id = 2` shouldn't have to wait for the first one as both table and index are partitioned and the index is aligned.

However this doesn't happen and when I check the execution plan, I see that the table scan happens on every partition even through that doesnt make sense to me.

I tried `technet`, `documentation` and `stackoverflow` but all I didn't find an answer.
Now I know that the `PK` should be `CAT_ID`, `PRD_ID` (this makes more sense the way the table is used)

I am currently working on `SQL Server 2012`, but I suppose it should work better then on `2008R2`.

Comment: Can you post the actual(!) execution plan of the update as XML (pastebin)? I don't see why this wouldn't work. I would expect lock escalation to X-lock the partition.